# 403 error from HttpWebResponse Instagram

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, instagram, http-status-code-403, httpwebresponse

First of all sorry for my bad english.
Task is to authenticate in instagram with API. When I try to get a token after the user clicked "OK" I get 403 error from HttpWebResponse and I can't get my token:(. I don't know what to do. Help me please. And when I enter this link in me browser - it's ok

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com" + url);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36";
request.Method = "POST";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control:max-age=0");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Host = "instagram.com";
request.Headers.Add("Origin: https://instagram.com");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write("csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + par + "&username=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD");
writer.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //403 ERORR
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an access token by simply sending a username/password pair to the API! You have to direct a real user to the Instagram's authorization url, and after the user logged in successfully Instagram will send your application a code to be used for getting the access token.

More information: https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/